# How to plot the graph between Q and J? Where, Q and J are variables

Tags: plotting

How to plot the graph between Q and J for the following equation? Here we can take  $l$ = 1.

$\frac{\pi Q^2 + \sqrt{\pi^2 Q^4 + \frac{16 J^2}{l^2} }}{8} + \frac{2 J^2}{l^2 \bigg(\sqrt{\pi^2 Q^4 + \frac{16 J^2}{l^2}}\bigg)} - \frac{\pi}{4} Q^2 ln\bigg[ \frac{l}{8} \bigg(\pi Q^2 + \sqrt{\pi^2 Q^4 + \frac{16 J^2}{l^2} } \bigg) \bigg]=0$

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: The community [expects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
❌: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html), $\LaTeX$ is excellent, but not enough. 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot[((Pi Q^2 + Sqrt[Pi^2 Q^4 + (16 J^2)/l^2])/8 + (2 J^2)/(
     l^2 (Sqrt[Pi^2 Q^4 + (16 J^2)/l^2])) - 
     Pi/4 Q^2 Log[l/8 (Pi Q^2 + Sqrt[Pi^2 Q^4 + (16 J^2)/l^2])] /. 
    l -> 1) == 2, {Q, -10, 10}, {J, -10, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

> [image: plot]